# What happened to the points from the WarGames movie?

Tags: ready-player-one

We see that for the challenge at the first gate, the player is supposed to

> act out the role of Matthew Broderick's character in WarGame.

The player receives bonus points for performing well and loses points if they make mistakes.

But after the challenge is complete we see that they get an even 100,000 points. So are the points within the challenge pointless (please excuse the pun)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you are talking about this:

> A green path appeared on the floor of the arcade, leading from where I stood to the exit. I started to follow it, then remembered to run back and grab my notebook off of the Dig Dug game, just like David had in the movie. **As I did this, my score jumped another 100 points, and ACTION BONUS! appeared on my display**.
>   <sub>Ready Player One - Chapter 11</sub>

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

This is important because later it explains that for every 700 points (or so) you get a "Cue Card Power Up".

> Whenever I correctly performed seven actions or recited seven lines of dialogue in a row, the game would award me a “Cue Card Power-Up.” The next time I blanked on what to do or say, I could select the Cue Card icon and the correct action or line of dialogue would appear on my display, sort of like a teleprompter.
>   <sub>Ready Player One - Chapter 11</sub>

It is unclear if failing to get an action bonus resets the streak necessary for the power-up, or if its a means of getting the power-up quicker. But either way, the points are only relevant in-gate to help the player while in-gate. Completing the gate will grant 100,000 points for the Scoreboard regardless of in-gate score.

Comment: So the none of the Action Bonus/points awarded don't matter, correct? You'd get the Cue Card regardless after seven correct actions in a row.

Comment: Well, I think it would allow you to get the power-up quicker. Since it’s additional actions you can earn by doing better.

Comment: I'm still not convinced since the points aren't tied to the cue cards anywhere. I guess it's just something the author wrote without really thinking about it.

Comment: @sudhanva So we do not know specifically for sure, but it is safe to assume the bonus points were tied to the cue cards to help speed up their acquisition; otherwise, what would be the in-game point of granting a bonus for doing extra, unnecessary work? And towards your initial question, it is doubtful that the 100k received was the end score of the gate, given that everyone got it and that would mean that everyone somehow ended up with the same score (somehow the mistakes, correct responses, and even bonus points all added up to the same end total for everyone)